# Get total memory size of an iso-15693 nfc device

Tags: ios, core-nfc, iso-15693

I have to get the total memory size in bytes of an iso-15693 NFC device. I downloaded several apps from App Store and they show me this information.

I'm new of NFC world, I looked at [`NFCISO15693Tag`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfciso15693tag) protocol in `CoreNFC` iOS framework but with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find that by accessing the NFCISO15693SystemInfo with the help of this CoreNFC [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfciso15693tag/3585163-getsysteminfo)

**Implementation**

```
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
    if case let .iso15693(tag) = tags.first{
        nfcIntegration.shared.nfcTagReaderSession?.connect(to: tags.first!, completionHandler: { [self] error in
            guard error == nil else{
                nfcIntegration.shared.nfcTagReaderSession?.alertMessage = "Problem with connection"
                return
            }
            tag.getSystemInfo(requestFlags: [.highDataRate]) { systemInfo in
                switch systemInfo {
                case .success(let success):
                        print("\(success.uniqueIdentifier)")
                case .failure(let failure):
                    print(failure.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

if the method return success result, you will get the details of the tag like below.

```
success(CoreNFC.NFCISO15693SystemInfo(uniqueIdentifier: 8 bytes, dataStorageFormatIdentifier: -1, applicationFamilyIdentifier: -1, blockSize: 8, totalBlocks: 244, icReference: -1))
```

With Blocksize and Totalblocks you can caluclate the total memory in bytes.